# Access Violation Exception in app that work with CSP

Tags: c#, .net, cryptoapi

I have a library on .NET Core for work with CSP. On rare occasions, this lib throws access violation exception. I don't know why because at other times all work well. I think it happens when lib searches certificates in the system store. I tried to log memory pointers to console before use unmanaged code but the output was empty when the program crashed. Other P/I requests are only to the CSP. Have you any ideas about how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Can you plz show us what have you tried that we could look?

Answer (score 0):

System Store certificates are only accessible to Administrators restart your app as an admin (or your visual studio if you're still developing that)